# How does gamma ray emission make an atom more stable?

Tags: radiation, atomic-physics, gamma-rays

One of the types of radioactive emissions is gamma emission. I understand how the other two types, alpha and beta, help to make the atom more stable. How exactly does gamma emission help to make the atom more stable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there an emission of gamma rays?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68902/)

Comment: also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55745/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a nucleus makes an alpha or beta decay, usually it's left in an excited state. It can make the transition to lower energy state by emitting gamma rays, so in a sense, the atom is more "stable" because the nucleus is in a lower energy state.

I am not sure if this answer your question. Hope it helps.

Comment: I see. So gamma emissions occur only after alpha or beta decay?

Comment: no, the nucleus could be in an excited state for other reasons, such as having formed by nuclear fusion, or having absorbed a gamma ray previously.

Answer (score 1):

The nucleus has [quantized energy levels](http://www2.lbl.gov/abc/wallchart/teachersguide/pdf/Chap06.pdf).  The emission of gamma rays is a transition from a higher energy level to a lower energy level.