# In the Pound Rebka Experiment, how were the gamma rays generated?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, nuclear-physics, experimental-technique, gamma-rays

Lest my question be dismissed as poorly-worded, let me first say that I do understand the concept of how a gamma ray is emitted when an electron in an excited (higher energy) state transitions to a lower state.  Also, I'm aware that they used $^{57}\text{Fe}$ as its photon energy (and thus gamma ray frequency) were/are well-known to an accurate value.

I've read the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment) and [this Physics SE question/answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/219149), but I still can't figure out...

## How did they get the $^{57}\text{Fe}$ electrons all excited to begin with?

Certainly the electrons in the iron samples don't maintain their excited state unless one keeps adding some external energy, correct?

Related side question: How difficult was it to get "enriched" $^{57}\text{Fe}$?  And, just how well-enriched were the samples?

Facetious side-question:  How loud could one hear the rumbling bass notes across the Harvard Campus while Dr. Pound and his student were running the experiment? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The photons in question were not atomic photons derived from relaxing an excitation of the electronic states of the atom. They were [nuclear photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68902/why-is-there-an-emission-of-gamma-rays) derived relaxing an [excited nuclear states](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55745/how-can-the-nucleus-of-an-atom-be-in-an-excited-state). The [excited state of Fe-57 is generated by the electron-capture decay](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286451/why-is-the-daughter-nucleus-left-in-an-excited-state-following-beta-decay-of-par) of [Cobalt-57](http://www.nucleide.org/DDEP_WG/Nuclides/Co-57_tables.pdf)

Colbalt-57 can be produced in quantities sufficient for use in this kind of experiment by putting a sample containing Cobalt-56 in a environment with high neutron flux such as near an operating nuclear reactor or a intense neutron source. Co-57 has a half life around nine months so it is well suited to this kind of application (long enough for the rate to be treated as constant over a few days, but short enough to get significant rate).

Comment: thank you for the quick answer... Plus, you automatically "answered" my side question.  Now I feel a little embarrassed about confusing electron vs. nuclear photons /gamma rays.   But, in my defense, the word "cobalt" is *NOT FOUND* on either of the two pages I linked. :-\